# Compare 2arrays of dictionary on one key and merge together

Tags: arrays, dictionary, ios13, swift5

I have two arrays. In first all categories and in second there are selected categories. I want to match those objects and then :  - Either I want to merge selected array into main array
- Or I want new array mapped with selected data.

Here is my arrays :

```
self.arrAllCategories = [
        [
            "_id": “1”,
            "category_name": "Table”,
            "is_selected" : false
        ],
        [
            "_id": “2”,
            "category_name": “Chair”,
            "is_selected" : false
        ],
        [
            "_id": “3”,
            "category_name": “Fan”,
            "is_selected" : false
        ],
        [
            "_id": “4”,
            "category_name": “WallFrame”,
            "is_selected" : false
        ]
    ]
```

And so on…. 
And selected categories array :

```
self.arrSelectedCats = [
    [
        "_id": “1”,
        "category_name": "Table”,
        "is_selected" : true
    ],
    [
        "_id": “3”,
        "category_name": “Fan”,
        "is_selected" : true
    ],
]
```

I have to display categories screen with selected categories in different style and non selected categories in just gray look. So How I can merge and get one array to load data in collection view ?

Answer (score 0):

```
let yourKey = "_id"
var nonSelected = arrAllCategories.filter{ !(arrSelectedCats.map { $0[yourKey] as? String }).contains(($0[yourKey] as? String)) }
print(nonSelected)
```

Try this :)